# maven multiple modules springbootr:boot run error

Tags: maven

error message:

> The POM for rc:common:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available

parent pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>rc</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-multiple-maven-modules</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>rest</module>
    <module>common</module>
</modules>
```

rest pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>rc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-multiple-maven-modules</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>rest</artifactId>
<name>zeyo rest</name>
<!--<version>1.0</version>-->
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>rc</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

common pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>rc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-multiple-maven-modules</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>common</artifactId>
<name>common</name>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Once you have a dependency called rc -> rest -> common.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

That simply says that `common` project not yet built and we started `rest`.

First run the maven install on parent project so that 'common' project will be built as well.

```
spring-boot:run : does not build the dependent jars.
```

Hope this helps.